# Adapter class or multiple interface implementations for IComparer, IComparer<T>

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, adapter, icomparer

I need to use a custom sorting algorithm on a WPF DataGrid's ListCollectionView.
I created an implementation of `IComparer<string>` since I use strings but the `CustomSort` property of `ListCollectionView`  only takes non-generic `IComparer` implementation:

```
listCollectionView.CustomSort = new MyComparer(); // this wont work
```

Since my comparing logic is specifically for strings while I need an `IComparer` instance, I was thinking about creating a `MyComparerAdapter` adapter like so:

```
public class MyComparerAdapter : IComparer
{
    private readonly IComparer<string> _innerComparer = new MyComparer();

    public int Compare(object a, object b)
    {
        return _innerComparer.Compare((string)a, (string)b);
    }
}
```

But I might as well implement the non-generic IComparer interface in the `MyComparer` class which would call the generic Compare method.

**Which solution would be more preferable and why? Would the adapter be a useless extra component in this? Is there a downside of implementing both the generic and the non-generic methods of IComparer?**

Comment: Can't comment of the pros and cons. I would  simply implement both. A good example would be the standard StringComparer. It implements almost all Comparer interfaces. See https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/stringcomparer.cs,a1c3d85bbf4ae20e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find less is more. Implementing the bare minimum and adding only when it's needed.

Translated to your case, it depends...

Do you see yourself **using the generic variant** anywhere (in your view models)?

#### No

The CollectionView is object based by nature. Implementing just IComparer will suffice.

#### Yes

Implement both on `MyComparer`. I've only used the Adapter / Decorator pattern when some pre- or postprocessing needed to be done.

Comment: Thank you! This question helped me see the situation more clearly. I don't even need the generic variant.